# Is my Chrome driver detected and refused by EToro server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, browser-detection

I try to log in a etoro with Chrome driver but an error message appears on the screen.

[image]

However I manage to do it very well by hand.

```
USER = config.username
PWD = config.password
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Programs\chromedriver.exe")
browser = driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/login")
try:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("i-menu-user-username")
except: pass
print("Logging in...")
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
elem.send_keys(USER)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
elem.send_keys(PWD)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
try:
    wait_ele = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'i-menu-user-username'))
    WebDriverWait( browser, 5 ).until(wait_ele)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("i-menu-user-username")
except TimeoutException: print("Loading took too much time!")
except: pass
if (elem!=None) and (elem.text==USER): print("logged in")
else: print("wtf?")
```

So how can I log in EToro using selenium?

I guess if that doesn't work I have another chance with transfering my account to a Google one?

Comment: I get the same error (even though I'm using PlayWright)

Comment: Getting the same error too, with Selenium